# SQL query works in interactive python console, not in script

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a python script that reads tables/values from a file and queries for something..

I've tested the query in the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, then the interactive python console.. both ways the query worked perfectly fine.

Now when I have the query in my script, it executes without error, but doesn't work.

Here's what I'm doing ([the query is from database administrators stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/83454/50917)):

```
#source table and destination table
src = 'TableA'
dst = 'TableB'

try:
    con.execute_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '+str(src))
    for row in con:
        print(row)
    print('SELECT * FROM '+str(src)+'; WITH cte AS (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY val1, val2 ORDER BY val1, val2 ) AS Picker FROM '+str(src)+') DELETE cte WHERE Picker > 1')
    con.execute_query('SELECT * FROM '+str(src)+'; WITH cte AS (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY val1, val2 ORDER BY val1, val2 ) AS Picker FROM '+str(src)+') DELETE cte WHERE Picker > 1')
    con.execute_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '+str(src))
    for row in con:
        print(row)
except Exception as e:
    print("SQL QUERY FAILED. Error:\n" + str(e))
    sys.exit(4)
```

the `print`s before and after the query are the ensure it worked or not (also checked in the management interface). They do show the correct number of entries though.
If i now copy/paste the exact same thing, on the same machine, same python version, to the interactive python terminal it works.

I'm so confused.. and getting angry.

Can someone tell me why this won't work in the script, but outside it will?

(Working on Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition v9.00.3042.00, i.e. SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2)

Comment: try to debug and check the value for str(src). Then check the queries are proper or not when used with str(src).

Comment: I `print(str(src))` and it shows exactly what I want. Also did i assign src to the same value in the interactive console, than in the script, run the same command and it worked.

Comment: Is any of the queries are working like this one: con.execute_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '+str(src)). Is this query working?

Comment: yes, they work perfectly fine, they retrieve the current total number of entries. I've double-checked, the number is correct.

Comment: Is COUNT query is working in the script??

Comment: Which query is not working in the script? Is it with CTE?

Comment: @PareshJ `con.execute_query('SELECT * FROM '+str(src)+'; WITH cte AS (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY val1, val2 ORDER BY val1, val2 ) AS Picker FROM '+str(src)+') DELETE cte WHERE Picker > 1')` is not working.

Comment: try using ';' before Delete CTE

Comment: @PareshJ that leads to `Incorrect syntax near ';'`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years from now, but I had the same issue and it turnt out to be that I wasn't in the same directory. If you don't run the code from the same directory where the db is, then it won't be able to read it. I'm not any expert, but for some reason it doesn't through any error, it just lets you run everything but it can't read any value from the database